# Find each Möbius transformation $f$ which maps $0 \rightarrow 1, 1 \rightarrow \infty, \infty \rightarrow 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find each Möbius transformation $f$ which maps $0 \rightarrow 1, 1 \rightarrow \infty, \infty \rightarrow 0$.

I think $$f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}$$ satisfies our requirement. But is there a general method solving this kind of prolems?

I was trying to use the cross ratio form like
$$f(z)=\frac{(z-z_1)(z_2-z_3)}{(z-z_3)(z_2-z_1)}$$But of course $z_1$ can't be $\infty$ here.

Thanks~

Comment: Yes, $z_1$ can be infinity. More rigorously, you take the limit $z_1\to\infty$, which cancels out the $z-z_1$ and $z_2-z_1$ factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to verify your answer.

Recall that a Mobius transformation is given by
$$f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d},$$ with $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb C$ and $ad-bc \neq 0$.

The $0 \rightarrow 1$ map implies

$$f(0)=\frac{b}{d}=1 \Rightarrow b=d.$$

The $1 \rightarrow \infty$ map implies

$$f(1)=\frac{b}{c+b}=\infty \Rightarrow c+b=0 \Rightarrow c=-b.$$

The $\infty \rightarrow 0$  map implies
$$f(\infty)=\frac{a}{c}=0 \Rightarrow a=0.$$

Thus, keeping $b$ as our free variable we get

$$f(z)=\frac{b}{b-bz}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Just write 
$$
f\left(z\right)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d},
$$
replace $z$ by $0$, $1$ and $\infty$, and solve the resulting
equations in the unknowns $a,b,c$ and $d$.

Answer (score 1):

Ass you say,
cross-ratios are preserved, so to find the linear fractional transformation
taking $a_1,a_2,a_3$ (all distinct) to $b_1,b_2,b_3$ (also all distinct) resp., solve
$$\frac{(f(z)-b_1)(b_2-b_3)}{(f(z)-b_2)(b_1-b_3)}
=\frac{(z-a_1)(a_2-a_3)}{(z-a_2)(a_1-a_3)}$$
for $f(z)$.