# Find Möbius transformation that maps $1 \rightarrow 1, -1 \rightarrow i, -i \rightarrow -1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find Möbius transformation that maps $1 \rightarrow 1, -1 \rightarrow  i, -i \rightarrow  -1$.

Since both the domain and the image are points on the unit circle, I was trying to use Möbius transformation as for $|a|<1$
$$f(z)=\frac{e^{i\theta}(z-a)}{1-\bar{a}z}$$
By plug in numbers I got one candicate could be
$$f(z)=\frac{e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}i}[z-(1-\sqrt{2})i]}{1+(1-\sqrt{2})zi}$$
However, I got 2 problems here: First, the calculations are too much. Second, when I plug back to this function the numbers in the problem I got
$$f(1)=1, f(-1)=i,f(-i)=\frac{1+i}{-\sqrt{2}}$$
:( Any help? Thanks~

Comment: See my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2584488/find-each-m%c3%b6bius-transformation-f-which-maps-0-rightarrow-1-1-rightarrow/2584516#2584516

Comment: Just follow the exact same method as outlined in your previous question.

Comment: @thesmallprint Thanks.  I tried that, but the calculations are too much. I was trying to see whether there is a simple way to do it.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks! Your method works! And much better than what I did!

Comment: @Nan Yeah, with this one you'll end up with a few hefty equations but it's one of the surefire ways to solve these types of questions.

Comment: @thesmallprint Thanks again! :)